# Anyone else interested in being able to put all one's questions on a single screen?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search

I frequently find myself in the situation that I'm sure someone on SO has helped me solve a particular problem at some time in the past, but I'm not sure when.  For such situations, it would be very helpful to be able to view all my prior questions on a single screen.  Then I could either quickly scan the questions or use my browser's "search" capability to look for a keyword.

Would anyone else be interested in such functionality?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of scanning through a list of all of your own questions manually, why not just search all of your questions? Using the `user:me` search operator, it can limit your search to only posts by you. Add in `views:0` or `is:question` and it will only cover questions. Then you can add on any additional search items you need to narrow down the search and find things.

I feel the search can basically accomplish anything one would need such an aggregate page for without needing to aggregate everything onto one page. And do a much better job, too, since it can search post bodies which would be cumbersome to list all on one page.